# Using one shared Join table for multiple many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-modeling, software-design

I have these SQL models: `Albums`, `Collections` and `Photos`.

Both `Albums` and `Collections` have a many-to-many and one-to-many relationships with `Photos` and serve different application purposes.

What are the pros and cons of having 2 join tables for this vs just 1 that looks like either of the following:

Option 1: `PhotoCollectable` (album and collection combined in the same row):

| photo_id | album_id | collection_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 |  | 5 |

Option 2: `PhotoCollectable` (album and collection separate rows):

| photo_id | album_id | collection_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 100 | c |
| 1 | 1 |  | a |
| 2 |  | 5 | c |

Assuming the join table should not have any other attributes in modeling, which option is recommended here (or should I still do separate join tables) and why (pros and cons)?

If the 2 join relationships do warrant different additional attributes, how would your answer change? Expecting some columns nullable while others aren't depending on the type?

Comment: as far as i can see you have only one table, but it should be two of them the second option is possible, but you would unnecessary waste if space

Comment: A basic course of relational database design will point to clearly separating entities and the relationships between them. Follow the tried and trusted patterns and keep relationships separate.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to put both relationships in same table - you are just complicating your application logic (e.g., you will require writing more code).

Create a PHOTO_ALBUM_REL table (within just 1 record per your example)

```
| PHOTO_ID | ALBUM_ID |
| 1        |     1    |
```

Create a PHOTO_COLLECTION_REL table (with just 2 records per your example)

```
| PHOTO_ID | COLLECTION_ID |
| 1        | 1             |
| 2        | 5             |
```

This eliminates all ambiguity and unnecessary checks/comparisons on type.

You also asked: 'If the 2 join relationships do warrant different additional attributes, how would your answer change?'.  If you think there will be additional attributes based on type, then having two separate tables sounds even better to me to avoid your next scenario of 'Expecting some fields nullable while others aren't depending on the type?'

It seems you already realize that having both relationships in the same table will result in a bunch of null values in columns.  Keeping them separate gives you a very clean design with no ambiguity.  It will also be easier to maintain in the long run.  For example, say you want to add some new attribute or capability to your collections capability -- you can do that without touching anything related to albums capability.

Good luck with your project!